# Column space and equation of the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

The column space of A is a plane. I need to find the equation of the plane.

Matrix $A$
$\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&6&4  
\\2&5&7&6   
\\2&3&5&2 
\end{bmatrix}$

My solution:

my logic is that vector b which is in the Col(A)

$\begin{bmatrix}
b_1  
\\b_2   
\\b_3
\end{bmatrix}$

Then Ax = b has a solution:

then,

$\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&6&4 = b_1  
\\2&5&7&6 = b_2    
\\2&3&5&2 = b_3
\end{bmatrix}$

when I reduced the matrix I produced(not sure if I did this part correctly)

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&2 = 1/2b_1  
\\0&1&1&2 = b_2-b_1   
\\0&0&0&0 = 2b_1-2b_2-b_3
\end{bmatrix}$

Not quite sure where to go from here or if my workings are correct to this point. Looking for some guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've determined is that $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $2b_1 - 2b_2 - b_3=0$. However, $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

So, an equation for the column space of $A$ is
$$
2x-2 y - z=0
$$
...or at least, this would be a way to find the equation of the plane if you had row-reduced correctly.

Comment: okay so I didn't need to go through all those workings ?

Comment: You did have to go through that work. I'm using your work. Apparently, however, you reduced the matrix incorrectly.

Comment: okay I was not sure if my worings were correct when I row reduced